# Ctags force prompt on ambiguous tag

Tags: ctags

I have a Python project where there are lots of functions with the same name in different files. Some symbols are reasonably unique and `C-]` will jump to the right definition. However, others are very common. Right now I look at the word and if it's something generic like `upload` I hit `g]` to be prompted for a list of possible definition sites. Is there a way to get the number of possible ctag matches for the word currently under the cursor so I can make `C-]` do `g]` when the symbol is ambiguous?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`g<C-]>` will display a list of tags only when there is more than one, so you could just train yourself to type `g<C-]>` instead of `<C-]>`. But having to type two characters instead of one, especially when one takes a modifier, is a pain, so what I would do is put this mapping in your ~/.vimrc:

```
:nnoremap <C-]> g<C-]>
```